# Internet Explorer prints HTML instead of the web page

Tags: printing, internet-explorer-8

I have problem printing web pages using Internet Explorer 8. Instead of printing the page, it prints HTML code instead. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

I'm using Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 1):

Resetting IE settings should fix this problem for you. To do this, follow these steps:

> Open Internet Explorer. 
>   Click Tools, and then click Internet Options. 
>   Click the Advanced tab. 
>   Under Reset Internet Explorer Settings, click Reset.

For more about what resetting IE settings does, visit http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Reset-Internet-Explorer-settings

Good Luck!

Cheers,
Cassandra
IE Outreach Team

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I tried it out, but still didn't work. =( ...Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/33460109/print-command-prints-source-instead-of-page.aspx) says making IE your default browser will fix the problem.

[This page](http://blog.ryantadams.com/2008/01/06/internet-explorer-only-prints-source-code/) says that uninstalling and then re-installing it will fix the problem.

I know they mention IE7, but I'd try the default browser one first.

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved this on a system by following the instructions [here](http://deinfotech.blogspot.ca/2012/02/internet-explorer-gave-blank-print.html)

Go into your "Default Programs".  Select "Set program access and computer defaults".  Then chose the "Microsoft Windows" option and apply.